# manipulation of equations in maxima

Tags: equation, maxima

I searched the maxima manual about how to manipulate the equation and the likes but I can't really find it.

I've already implemented coefmatrix in terms of ratcoef and using lhs and rhs. To finish it and proceed to augmented part, I need to know how to do this.

How can I make this:

```
x + 10 - y = z + 5;
```

turn into this:

```
x - y - z = -5;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do it. (1) I assume that you have already figured out how to get the coefficients via `ratcoef` and the right-hand side via `rhs`. Let `foo` be the right-hand side minus the left-hand side (so now you have `right - left = 0`. Subtract the sum of all the variables times their coefficients from that. Then the remainder is the constant part that doesn't depend on any variable. (2) Use `freeof` to identify terms which are free of (i.e., do not contain) any variable.

Comment: How can I do this?

Subtract the sum of all the variables times their coefficients from that

I tried freeof but only returns true or false

Comment: Well, for (1) presumably you have a list of variables and a corresponding list of coefficients. Then `apply("+", vlist * clist)` is the sum of variables times their coefficients (with `vlist` = variable list and `clist` = coefficient list). As for (2), note that you can extract all non-variables terms in a "+" expression like this: `sublist(args(e), lambda ([e1], apply(freeof, append(vlist, [e1]))))` where `e` is the "+" expression and `vlist` is the list of variables (e.g., `[x, y, z]`).

Comment: thanks, now i've got the correct answer. I used the former way.. thanks

Comment: i added those manually. haha. every loop, i get the coefficient * variable from a list. from the rhs-lhs. then subtract from original  equation. thanks :)